# Interact between controller inside an iframe to controller outside of it Angular js

Tags: angularjs, iframe

I had a html where I had an `iframe` and a `div` which had a `button` inside it. To this html I had a parent controller. Now inside the `iframe` I'm calling another html which had a `button` along with a child controller to that html. Now I want to hide the `div` which is in the main html page, when I click the button inside the `iframe`.

So I want interaction between two different controllers, between parent and child of different htmls. I came to know we should use service and $parent scope to achieve this kind of thing but I am unable to make it work. So can someone please help me in this, if you have come across such thing.Thanks!

Here is the plunkr :http://plnkr.co/edit/tpxo5gMZ87dKWampmdOK?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

here is a link to updated plunker (http://plnkr.co/edit/EYpEATLGd0B54WpEr7II?p=preview) which has two way communication parent to child and child to parent. Two way binding if needed may be achieved in the same manner by using watchers:

app.js

```
appInParentWindow.controller('ParentController', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.$on('from-iframe', function(e, hide) {
    // toggle visibility
    $scope.parentbtn = !$scope.parentbtn;
  });

  $scope.message = function () {
    // get child scope, we do not use factory since frame is not there yet in that phase
    $childScope = $window.frames[0].angular.element($window.frames[0].frameElement).scope();

    $childScope.$apply(function () {
      $childScope.$emit('from-parent', $scope.messageText);
    });
  };
});
```